# What does this import exactly mean in Scala?

Tags: scala, syntax, import

I encountered the following in Scala code:

```
class MyClass {
  ...
  val a = new A; import a._

}
```

What does exactly `val a = new A; import a._` mean ?

Answer (score 15):

It imports the methods and variables of the a object. So if you want to call `a.foo()`, you can just call `foo()` instead.

Answer (score 9):

It means that all methods and variables of `a` object of `A` type are now available in this block (scope) without explicitly mentioning `a`. So if `A` has a `bar()` method you can now say:

```
bar()
```

instead of

```
a.bar()
```

but only within the scope where `import` is defined.

Answer (score 7):

Let's explain this with something you should be familiar with:

```
println("Hello world")
```

The question is: why does that work? There's no object called `println` with an `apply` method, which is the usual explanation for code that looks like that. Well, as it happens, the above code is really doing this:

```
Predef.println("Hello world")
```

In other words, `println` is a method on the object `scala.Predef`. So, how can you use it like above? Well, like this:

```
import scala.Predef._
println("Hello world")
```

Importing the contents of *a stable reference*  (ie, not a `var` or a `def`) will make its methods available without having to prefix them with `reference.`.

It also makes any implicits defined inside it available, which is how the implicit conversions defined inside `scala.Predef` are made available as well -- Scala imports the contents of `java.lang`, `scala` and `scala.Predef` (in that order, so the latter ones override the earlier ones).